# Auth0 Redirect going to the wrong address

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have my app located at https://www.pprhr.com/portal

However, when trying to login or out, it redirects to https://www.pprhr.com, which is incorrect, it's missing "portal" on the end.  I cannot find where I set the redirectUri to the correct path.  It does show in the logs that it is indeed pointing to the wrong path. I cannot find where to change it though.

My index.js simpley has this line:  redirect_uri={window.location.origin}

Do I need to change this?

All of the callbacks in the application settings on the Auth0 site to have https://www.pprhr.com/portal

Answer (score 0):

Please open your developer tools, go into the console and type:

window.location.origin

You will see that it isn't giving you the URL you want

Instead, the href property is what you want.